# fetching mysql error into <div>

Tags: jquery, mysql-error-1064

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pop1").click(function(){
        $("#shadow").fadeIn("normal");
         $("#form1").fadeIn("normal");
         $("#firstname").focus();
    });
    $("#cancel_hide").click(function(){
        $("#form1").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#shadow").fadeOut();
   });
   $("#insert").click(function(){    
        fname   =$("#firstname").val();
        lname   =$("#lastname").val();
        addr    =$("#adres").val();
        city    =$("#city").val();
        state   =$("#state").val();
        zip     =$("#zip").val();
        tel     =$("#phone").val();
        email   =$("#email").val();
        ip      =$("#ip").val();
        source  =$("#source").val();
        date    =$("#date").val();
         $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "save.php",
            data    : "fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&addr="+addr+"&city="+city+"&state="+state+"&zip="+zip+"&tel="+tel+"&email="+email+"&ip="+ip+"&source="+source+"&date="+date,
            success : function(html){                       
              if(html=='true')
              {
                $("#form1").fadeOut("normal");
                $("#shadow").fadeOut();
                $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>");                          
              }else{
                $("#add_err").html("Wrong username or password");               
              }
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                 $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
            }
        });
         return false;
    });
});
```

my index.php file is obove

how can i print error which occur in save.php  into   in index.php

for examlple how can i pring this output into div in index.php
echo "Hata No : ".mysql_errno()."
 Hata Mesajý :".mysql_error();

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is returning HTML you can write it out like this assuming you have a div with an id="result" -

```
if(html=='true') {
    $('#result').text(html);
    // rest of your code here
```

Of course you may want to check what is being returned in your HTML so that you know if you want to show this information or not.